# Unable to use pykml library, "moduleNotFountError" error every time

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pykml

I can't use the pykml library with Python 3.10, I get an moduleNotFoundError return every time. I installed with pip install pykml, installation successful but moduleNotFoundError.
I downloaded the tar.zip folder and installed with python setup.py install, successful install but still moduleNotFoundError. Each time, I checked the presence of the files in the site-packages folder.
I am at the end of my resources and cannot find more info on this situation.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice carelessness on my part, I recently moved from Python 9 to Python 10 and my VisualStudioCode has kept the Python 9 interpreter. That's why when I installed modules with Python 10, I don't I could not solicit them with the Python 9 interpreter. I configured VSC with the Python 10 interpreter and everything works perfectly. If that can help someone.